# OpenLayers: Zoom level changes to non-round number after OL6 upgrade

Tags: zooming, openlayers-6

We upgraded from OL5.3 to OL6.1.1 recently and I noticed that OL handles the zoom level somehow differently.

Previously, the zoom level would always be a whole number, even after rotating the map or using the "zoom to layer" function; right after the interaction, OL would always round the zoom level down to the next lower whole number.

Based on the release notes for 6.0.0, I suspect it has something to do with `constrainResolution`. Can someone give me a hint? How can we restore the previous behaviour?

Comment: You now need to include `constrainResolution: true` in the view options

Comment: Hello @Mike, thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. If you like you can post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as accepted.